# TextView misbehaving when appending two strings

Tags: android, unicode, textview

I am working on writing a simple temperature conversion program, to familiarize myself with Android programming.  The user types in a number to an `EditText`, and it converts it from Fahrenheit to Celsius, or vice versa, then puts the answer in a `TextView`.  I want to append a Unicode Celsius/Fahrenheit symbol to the end of the answer before displaying it.  When I don't have it appending the symbol, it works fine and displays the correct number, but when it is trying to append the symbol to the end, the output displays all wrong, with a long string of numbers at the end (and still no Unicode symbol).

Here's my code:

This is the converter utility class:

```
public class ConverterUtil {

    //Convert to celsius
    public static String convertFahrenheitToCelsius(float fahrenheit) {
        float temperature = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
        return df.format(temperature) + R.string.celsius_symbol;
    }

    //Convert to fahrenheit
    public static String convertCelsiustoFahrenheit(float celsius) {
        float temperature = (celsius * 9) / 5 + 32; //Append the unicode Celsius symbol (\u2103), then return

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");a
        return df.format(temperature) + R.string.fahrenheit_symbol; //Append the unicode Fahrenheit symbol (\u2109), then return
    }
}
```

And this is where I call it:

```
public void calculateTemperature(){

        RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

        if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
            output.setText("");
            return;
        }

        float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());
        String outputText = celsiusButton.isChecked() ? ConverterUtil.convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue) : ConverterUtil.convertCelsiustoFahrenheit(inputValue);

        output.setText(outputText);
    }
```

If I take out the part where I append the Unicode symbols, it looks like this:
[image]

And if I put that back in, I get this:
[image]

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the resourceID of your fahrenheit_symbol & celsius_symbol are getting appended to your text than the actual character.

Try this,

```
public class ConverterUtil {

    //Convert to celsius
    public static String convertFahrenheitToCelsius(Context context, float fahrenheit) {
        float temperature = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
        return df.format(temperature) + context.getResources().getString(R.string.celsius_symbol);
    }

    //Convert to fahrenheit
    public static String convertCelsiustoFahrenheit(Context context, float celsius) {
        float temperature = (celsius * 9) / 5 + 32; //Append the unicode Celsius symbol (\u2103), then return

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");a
        return df.format(temperature) + context.getResources().getString(R.string.fahrenheit_symbol); //Append the unicode Fahrenheit symbol (\u2109), then return
    }
}
```

Change where you call it like this,

```
public void calculateTemperature(){

    RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

    if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
        output.setText("");
        return;
    }

    float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());
    String outputText = celsiusButton.isChecked() ? ConverterUtil.convertFahrenheitToCelsius(YourActivity.this, inputValue) : ConverterUtil.convertCelsiustoFahrenheit(YourActivity.this, inputValue);

    output.setText(outputText);
}
```

Comment: Cool, that worked!  So how does that work? What is `context.getResources().getString()`?

Comment: In your project there will be a generated `R.java` file, all resources in your project are assigned a unique integer resource ID. You can use either getString(int) or getText(int) to retrieve the string at this resource ID.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return df.format(temperature) + R.string.fahrenheit_symbol;
return df.format(temperature) + R.string.celsius_symbol;
```

to

```
return df.format(temperature) + getString(R.string.fahrenheit_symbol);
return df.format(temperature) + getString(R.string.celsius_symbol);
```

`R.string.fahrenheit_symbol` and `R.string.celsius_symbol` are both integers. You will need to look up the relevant string resource using `Context.getResources().getString()`.

You will need to pass a `Context` (such as the calling `Activity`) to your `ConverterUtil`.